# How can I make the button boxes connect?

Tags: html, css, button, flexbox, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator using HTML, CSS and Javascript. This is just the raw CSS and HTML. Please how do I make all the borders of the buttons meet since I used flex grow.

**EDIT:** I'm sorry about the old code pen link, this is the new and working one
https://codepen.io/philippaolomoro/pen/abOwoNd

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Calculator using flex</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="screen-container">
            <div class="screen-input">
                0
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="buttons">
            <div class="rows row1">
                <button class="clear">C</button>
                <button>&#8592;</button>
                <button>&divide;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="rows row2">
                <button>7</button>
                <button>8</button>
                <button>9</button>
                <button>x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="rows row3">
                <button>4</button>
                <button>5</button>
                <button>6</button>
                <button>-</button>
            </div>
            <div class="rows row4">
                <button>1</button>
                <button>2</button>
                <button>3</button>
                <button>+</button>
            </div>
            <div class="rows row5">
                <button class="zero">0</button>
                <button>=</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** My CSS is in my code pen link.

Comment: codepen you provided is not available

Comment: Where is your CSS?

Comment: I just edited the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the grid instead of the flexbox, it's perfect for your situation.

```
.rows {
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr) 
}

.clear {
grid-column: 1/3
}

.zero {
grid-column: 1/4
}
```

You can read more about the css grid here:
[CSS GRID](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you give `font-size 0` to your parent element, it should remove whitespace between your buttons which cause additional space between them.

Add the following to your css:

```
.buttons{
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your codepen link is not working.
However, one possible solution is to set a width to your rows and add a flex-grow property to the last button of each row:

```
<style>
    .rows{
        display: flex;
        width: 100px;
    }
    .rows button:last-of-type{
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
</style>
```